# Independent probability and a pattern recognition from the data set

Tags: probability, finance, data-analysis

I am a uni student and currently majoring in Finance.

As far as I am concerned and If I recall my 'STAT 101' module correctly, independent events are not affected by previous events.

My question is that - the dataset you get from independent events is useless?

Let's assume that you are a hedge fund manager and you deal with **binary stock options** and the probability of it is the same as a coin toss. **50:50**

However, purely based on the stock chart within a certain time frame (ignoring all other factors such as fundamentals, breaking news and etc), you see a certain pattern. Let's say the winning rate is 70%.

If you try to come up with a strategy with regards to that chart, are you a good fund manager or a bad one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what you are after here.   Obviously, if the market sells you a bet at $50-50$ odds and you win $70\%$ of them, that's good.  It's also hard to believe.

Comment: you are doing better than a random generator, so you are doing better than nothing. But you cannot define good, based on one measurement (one fund manager in this case), just like you cannot define a mean, based on one number.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Is it a 'Monte Carlo fallacy' tho? Despite the fact that you are expecting 70 winning rates, it is an independent probability so the results/previous data means nothing? or Can we ACTUALLY implement this data when you see a certain pattern.

Comment: You've provided almost no information or data, so we clearly can not say much about the actual pattern.  What analysts generally do when they've spotted a supposed pattern is to test it on "clean" data...that is, data that was not previously used.  If no clean historical data exists, then you can study the performance of the pattern over time.  That is, just place virtual bets for a while to see how the pattern holds up.

Comment: It is extremely unlikely that the value of a stock on one day is independent of its value on the previous day.  Math texts are full of problems where the events are assumed to be independent. It easy to fall into the trap of assuming events in the Real World are independent when they might not be.